# How to Implements multiple Dynamic Spinner with different item list and different action on click in the same Activity

Tags: android, android-spinner

How to Implements multiple Dynamic Spinner with different item list and different action on click in the same Activity.
For example : length is 5 then "5 spinner" will be in activity.
if length is 2 then "2 spinner" will be in activity and may all spinner have different values.

Answer (score 0):

Add spinners dynamically and then add there content dynamically (by java code ) See this link: http://goo.gl/XrlIfi